# Decreasing The Timer Variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timer

This sample program starts the timer in 1000ms when the button is clicked and the Score variable is printed continuously on the screen. When the Score become 100, I want the timer to run in 500ms. When the Score become 300, I want the timer to run in 250ms.

My Start fuction and Score function in the ts file is below:

```
public ScoreNumber: number = 0;
public TimeOfScore;
public Start() {
    this.TimeOfScore= setInterval(() => {
        this.Score();
    }, 1000);

public Score(){
ScoreNumber++;
}
```

Start function calls with button in the html file. The score print on the screen like that:

```
<div>{{Score}}</div>
```

I changed the code like that:

```
public ScoreNumber: number = 0;
public TimeOfScore;
public time:number=1000;
public Start() {
    this.TimeOfScore= setInterval(() => {
        this.Score();
    }, time);

public Score(){
ScoreNumber++;
if(this.ScoreNumber>100&&this.ScoreNumber<300){
this.time=500;
}
else if(this.ScoerNumber>300){
this.time=250;
}    
}
```

Naturally the code did not work as I wished. Because the Start function calls only one time. How can I decrease this time variable?

Answer (score 0):

clear interval and set it again

```
if(this.ScoreNumber>100&&this.ScoreNumber<300){
this.time=500;
this.restartInterval();
}
else if(this.ScoerNumber>300){
this.time=250;
this.restartInterval();
}
```

Restart interval function

```
restartInterval()
{
    clearInterval(this.TimeOfScore);
    this.TimeOfScore= setInterval(() => {
        this.Score();
    }, this.time);
}
```

Comment: There's no point in using an interval if you clear it every time it runs.

Comment: interval is not cleared in every pass it cleared with specific condition like score is 100, 300 ect

Answer (score 0):

1) just use a recursive setTimeout
2) follow the javascript conventions!

```
 private scoreNumber: number = 0;
 private duration: number = 1000;
 private running = false;

 public start(){
   if(this.running) return;
   this.running = true;
   run();
 }

 private run(){
   this.scoreNumber++;
   if(this.scoreNumber > 100 && this.scoreNumber < 300){
     this.duration = 500;
   } else if(this.scoreNumber > 300){
     this.duration = 250;
   } 
   setTimeout(run, this.duration);
}
```